# Safari can't connect to localhost

Tags: network, safari, dns

I'm trying to use Focus, an app that redirects blocked websites through `localhost`. However, while this works properly with Chrome and Firefox, Safari gives me an error message as in the attached image.

If in the web address I replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` everything works fine. How can I fix this?

The content of my `/private/etc/hosts` file is the default one, i.e.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

[image]

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of my proxies.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this didn't help, ignore it.

This might be related to [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). Different browsers deal with it in different ways. Do you have any non-Apache local web server installed? I'm assuming there's something to do with Focus that's running on port 8919 from your screenshot.

Try this: Quit Safari, make a backup of `~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist` somewhere safe, delete `~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist`, start Safari, and try that URL again. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed your instructions and unfortunately nothing changed. You are right that Focus is running something on port 8919, and as I said I can open that correctly with other browsers. Also, how would I check if I have any local web servers installed?

Comment: Try commenting out the IPv6 lines in `hosts`: `#::1` and `#fe80::1%lo0` -- any luck?

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: I'll take a closer look since curiosity is getting the better of me -- there are numerous apps for macOS called Focus, can you reply with a link to the one you're using and I'll have a poke around. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks again! [Here it is](https://heyfocus.com), however I don't think the issue is with this app in particular.

Comment: Have you got anything special in system proxies? System Preferences -> Network -> select your current adaptor -> Advanced -> Proxies. Any chance you could post a screenshot (minus anything sensitive)?

Comment: I edited the original question and added the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you. Final avenues I can think of right now…what Safari extensions do you have installed? Also, quit Safari, and clear your local DNS cache: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`. And it's a long shot, does the content of `/etc/hosts/` match that of `/private/etc/hosts'?

Comment: The only extension I have is 1Blocker, an adblocker I downloaded from the App Store. Disabling it doesn't make any difference. Same thing after clearing the DNS cache. Finally, the content of `/etc/hosts/` and `/private/etc/hosts` matches exactly.